# sql update column 2 with column 1 data

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-update

Wordpress has 2 columns in its ***wp_posts*** table

- post_date (the actual date post was published)
- post_modified (the last time the post was modified)

I want to update/change/replace post_modified values with the values of post_date but haven't a clue how to except knowing I need a sql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_modified= post_date
```

Comment: Thanks Arion will mark as answer when I can, was actually the other way around (post_modified = post_date) but neither the less correct, can't believe it was so simple lol  :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. It is just sql 101 :P

Answer (score 1):

```
Update wp_posts
set w1.post_modified = w2.post_date
from wp_posts w1, wp_posts w2 
where w1.IdCol = w2.IdCol
```

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, I think @Anna is confusing the word row with the word column, but +1 for taking the time to answer the question as originally stated.